# Hiding the time in a datetime model field in Django?

Tags: python, django, datetime, schedule

I'm using Thauber's [lovely Django schedule app](http://github.com/thauber/django-schedule), but have run into a problem: I can't figure out how to exclude the time portion of the datetime field.

My form class and lame exclusion attempt looks like this:

```
 class LaundryDeliveryForm(EventForm):
    start = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.SplitDateTimeWidget)
    end = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.SplitDateTimeWidget, help_text = ("The end time must be later than start time."))
    class Meta:
        model = LaundryDelivery 
        exclude = EventForm.Meta.exclude + ('active', 'start.time')
```

Ideally, I'd like to just store the day, or store the start.time as some arbitrary time like 8 a.m., but while the active field is happily excluded, the time field remains open.

Tried sifting through the documentation but couldn't track what I needed down.

Comment: Date fields appears to break a lot of stuff with schedule. It would be better if I could put some default as the time for the datetime field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use, `DateInput widget` as widget for current form, or `forms.DateField()`, which has default `DateInput` widget.

Comment: Ok, that was very helpful! But now I lose my beautiful calendar widget since it switches the id on it from id="id_start_0" to id="id_start". All the CSS that comes with Thauber's module is aligned to the latter naming convention, any ideas on how I can keep the ID_0 with the date picker?

Comment: Ok, thinking about it some more I might be asking for the impossible/impractical and should just suck up and fix the CSS.